# Spring lost model attribute between GET and POST

Tags: java, spring, jsp

The get method will prepare the model and send to the "add person" jsp

It will also set the "mode" attribute to be "add" (so add and edit can share same jsp)

When the processSubmit result hasErrors ,mode attribute is gone

How to maintain mode attribute between calls?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/people/def/add" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String personAdd(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person,Model map) {        
    map.addAttribute("mode", "add");
    //DO SOME LOGIC
    return "personAdd";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/people/def/add" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person,BindingResult result) { 
    personValidator.validate(person, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        //MODE ATTRIBUTE IS LOST
        return "personAdd";
```

Comment: Request attributes live only for the life of request.  So, if you want "mode" back in Post, you may have to submit it back as part of POST, may be by using hidden form control in your web form

Comment: How to add non bean attribute as hidden? like <form:hidden path="mode"/> ?

Comment: Yes.  And I think you have to add "@RequestParam("mode") String mode" to your "processSubmit" method to retrieve the value of mode from HTTP POST parameters

Comment: Works great Thanks!, can you post your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Welcome! Posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request attributes live only for the life of request. So, if you want "mode" back in Post, you may have to submit it back as part of POST, may be by using hidden form control in your web form.

You have to add "@RequestParam("mode") String mode" to your "processSubmit" method to retrieve the value of mode from HTTP POST parameters

Comment: just to note that whenever it suits you, you can avoid passing attributes through hidden controls by making them a session attribute (using @SessionAttributes list) - if you can use sessions